# Is std::any_of required to follow short circuit logic?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-lawyer

Given the following code,

```
std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::any_of(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), 
            [](int number) { return number > 3; } );
```

is std::any_of required (by the standard) to return as soon as it reaches 4?

Comment: That is: It's obvious that it *should* return as soon as the decision is known, but **must** it? Still, I don't really see why such questions need to be asked, instead of just reading the Standard to see.

Comment: While this conceptually resembles ORing the results of the predicate for all the elements, it probably doesn't get unrolled to a single statement using `operator ||` in the majority of cases, so I don't think that really indicates whether short-circuiting would occur either way... though sure, common sense does.

Comment: @underscore_d: I'm not convinced by that. The single answer at my time of writing seems to preclude the C++ standard library having a potential optimisation for a sorted container; that would otherwise use an O(log N) type approach. It still could, but it would have to track backwards along the container to pick out the first element satisfying the condition. It's this kind of detail that makes this **question a very good one**.

Comment: To the person who voted to close this as primarily opinion based: What?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The standard itself doesn't place any such hard requirement. But one may infer it is indirectly encouraged ([[alg.any_of]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.any_of)):

> ```
> template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
>   bool any_of(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);
> template <class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIterator, class Predicate>
>   bool any_of(ExecutionPolicy&& exec, ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
>               Predicate pred);
> ```
>
> *Returns*: false if [first, last) is empty or if there is no iterator i in the range [first, last) such that pred(*i) is true, and true
>   otherwise.
>
> *Complexity*: At most last - first applications of the predicate.

While a perfectly conforming implementation may apply the predicate *exactly* `last-first` times, the wording to me sounds like it would be encouraged to exit as soon as possible.

Note that it's virtually impossible to ask the same of the overload that accepts an `ExecutionPolicy`. Since then the order of evaluation is not known.

On a less formal note, any implementation of the sequential version that *does not* exit the moment the predicate is true, puts the credentials of its author into question.

Comment: The standard shouldn't mandate the exact order and count anyway because it may preclude optimizations that depend on the container and predicate types. E.g. `any_of(begin(intSet), end(intSet), [](int i) { return i > 500 && i < 1000; })` could be translated to something involving `intSet.upper_bound(500);`. Or the container is (partially) contiguous and the compiler generates SIMD. Or there is a different order in which the container elements can be accessed more efficiently. All of this will, granted, still work under the as-if rule, if the predicate has no side effects.

Comment: What intrigues me is that `[alg.any_of]` is in section _"Non-modifying sequence operations"_ `[alg.nonmodifying]` but nothing disallow an unpure predicate: `any_of(begin(numbers), end(numbers), [](int& number) { return --number > 2; } )`. gcc & clang implementations do stop before reaching the end of the range.

Comment: @YSC - They are in that section because they accept only a predicate. [And well...](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/algorithms.requirements#6) violating a shall not requirement is usually just a promise of UB.

Comment: @YSC - What perplexes me is that `std::for_each` is there as well. Because it isn't constrained to accepting a plain predicate.

Comment: @StoryTeller th'ats ok, `for_each` has an _Effects_ ([`[alg.foreach]/2`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.nonmodifying#alg.foreach-2)) section and [`[algorithms.requirements]/4`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/algorithms.requirements#4) says it's ok for its predicate to be non-constant if the iterator is mutable.

Comment: ... well maybe I over-interpret :/

Comment: @YSC - Actually, both you and I are misinterpreting. The section is called "non-modifying" because all the algorithms work in place. The "modifying" section has algorithms that produce an output range (via otuput iterator).

Comment: Wouldn't short circuiting make the parallelized version (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing#any_of) of the algorithm pointless?

Comment: @elik - Not really. If the parallelized version divides the range and each unit short circuits itself it's still an improvement.

Comment: @StoryTeller: But when you do that, any_of is not short circuiting anymore as it doesn't stop, globally, on the first occurrence of a value fulfilling the condition

Comment: @elik - So? It's not required to short-circuit globally.

Comment: @StoryTeller: How can you claim that a function is short circuiting if the implementation decides to divide the problem and only respects the short circuiting for its subproblems. Would you say a sort is stable if it gives you an unstable result, but claim that when it parallelized it, the subproblems were sorted in a stable way? Short circuiting implies that you should't evaluate something later in the list if something earlier fulfils the condition.

Comment: @elik - Where did I claim it's short circuited? The very first sentence in my answer is that there is no such requirement. My analysis of the specification was to explain why it's reasonable to expect a naive non-specialized, non-parallelized implementation to be shirt circuited regardless.